# Undo and redo not working after changing the hotkey

Tags: shortcut

[image][image]

I changed the undo and redo hotkeys from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd>, and now they are not even working and I have checked multiple times in keymap to make sure the hotkeys are properly set. But still <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> don't work for undo and redo.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found out that that F1 key was already attached to "View Online Manual" and so i had to remove it first, which i did and it fixed the undo and simultaneously the f2/redo also worked ( since before there was nothing to redo).